# How to convert jstl/JSP variables to javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, jstl

Is it possible to convert jstl/JSP variables to javascript variables?

Here is the JSTL:

```
 <c:forEach var="responseString" items = "${responseString}">
     <c:out value="${responseString.response}" />  
 </c:forEach>
```

I want to transfer the value inside **${responseString.response}** to a javascript **var response**

HERE is the javascript function:

> directionsService.route(request, function(**response**, status)

I tried this tutorial;

```
var response = {
<c:forEach var="responseString" items = "${responseString}">
    <c:out value="${responseString.response}" />
</c:forEach>
}
```

Obviously it didn't work, I kind of screwed it up, please help.

Added info, ${responseString.response} is actually `JSON`, I just converted it to `String`:

> {"routes": [{"bounds" : {"northeast":{"lat":14.650,"lng":121.050610}, "status":"OK"}

It's a deeply nested `JSON`.

Comment: Can you simply put `var response = ` before the JSON string? If it's valid JSON it should work correctly. You might look at a JSON library and then decode/reencode for display.

Comment: @artlung, the JSON is actually from google map api,  i already had parsed the JSON, passed it as STRING, but i cant convert the string to javascript variable

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
  var availableTags = [
  <c:forEach items="${vendorMap}" var="vendor" varStatus="vendorStatus">
     '<c:out value="${vendor}" />'
     <c:if test="${!vendorStatus.last}">    
     ,    
     </c:if> 
  </c:forEach>
 ];
```

Note that you should not add "," for the last entry and also single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Since you use for each, I assume it will be more than one response, thus instead `var response = {` you should use array `[]`. Try:

```
var response = [
<c:forEach var="responseString" items = "${responseString}">
    <c:out value="${responseString.response}" />,
</c:forEach>
];
```

Notice `,` after each element.

**edit on request:**

```
for(var i in response){
   PUSH_TO_GOOGLE_MAPS_WIDGET(response[i]);
}
```

`response[i]` will be like `{"routes": [{"bounds" : {"northeast":{"lat":14.650,"lng":121.050610}, "status":"OK"}`.

Comment: it still doesnt work, if i add your code, google maps  i previously had disappears, i would assume, something is wrong. the code is written within <script type="text/javascript"> right? sory 4 being noob

Comment: the ${responseString.response} is just a plain String in JSON format. how can i transfer it to javascript **var** using JSTL foreach? please help.

Comment: I don't know what are u going to do with response next, if u want to get every single response from response array and push it to google maps widget you must iterate over `response` array...

Comment: thatis what i want to do, push it to google maps. how do you iterate over response? can you give exmple pelase